# GitHub Actions only outputting DLL file

Tags: c#, .net, build

I recently tried automatically building and uploading my C# project. The build works fine, but the artifact sadly only contains a DLL file, and not a .exe file. When I build it locally, it outputs an .exe and a DLL file. Is that normal? This is my github actions file:

```yaml
    name: .NET

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build the app
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest


    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.0.x
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build
    - name: Upload a Build Artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2.2.2
      with:
        # Artifact name
        name: buildresult #.zip will be added automatically
        path: /home/runner/work/ParadoxicalLauncher/ParadoxicalLauncher/ParadoxicalLauncher/bin/Debug/net6.0/*.*
```

Comment: What OS are you building locally? Linux OS don't use the .exe extension for executable files, so you would likely get a file just named ParadoxicalLauncher. If you want to build an exe, then you'll want to run the build targeting a specific OS (win-x64)

Comment: I am using Windows to build locally. Your explanation sounds logical, but when It builds, the artifact only includes a dll file, not even a ParadoxicalLauncher file.
Not sure why

Comment: The reason why your application doesn't have an executable file is because you are only building it. .NET Core [requires executable applications to be published](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli) prior to deployment.

Comment: If you are used to building on Windows, it might be easier to use a Windows builder as well. Normally, .NET can cross-build from linux to windows or vice-versa, this is not guaranteed to always work (namely when you have gui components in your application)